# MS SQL Server Stored Procedure call | java

Tags: java, sql-server, java-stored-procedures

I am using MS SQL Server 2012 . Trying to make a call to stored procedure using java. Fields in database are varchar and int. I am using the below code:

```
String sql = "{call spu_getDetail('17537650',1)}";
Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db,username,password);
CallableStatement  statement = conn.prepareCall(sql);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(); // shows error here
```

When i execute i am getting an error as below

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error convering daata type varchar to smallint**

Please anybody help me here.!!

Comment: Can you show us the stored procedure?

Comment: Seems like the procedure expects a tiny int and int, or somewhere inside it uses the varchar as a tinyint. This doesn't look like it has anything to do with the java code.

Comment: Could anyone tell how to represent bit in callable statement? i think thats the issue..

Comment: i tried setting to boolean using setBoolean(2,true) . But never worked